# Pygame Boundary Not Working

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a kid in middle school and hope to be a programmer when I grow up.I'm going to a summer school coding class and learning python and pygame.I already knew enough python but just got my hands wet in pygame.I was adding trying to add a boundary for my game but it's able to block the left and top of the screen here is my code:

```
  import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400

pg = "player.gif"
bg = "y.gif"
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
background = pygame.image.load(bg)
player = pygame.image.load(pg)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
        sys.exit
        x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        screen.blit(background,[0,0])
        screen.blit(player,(x,y))
        pygame.display.update()
        if x <= WIDTH:
         x = 0
        if y <= HEIGHT:
         y = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if x <= WIDTH:
  x = 0
if y <= HEIGHT:
  y = 0
```

Is this really what you want to do? Set `x` and `y` to zero whenever the mouse is positioned within the boundaries? OR do you want to limit `x` and `y` to only existing within the range from 0 to `WIDTH` or `HEIGHT` respectively?

```
x = min(max(x, 0), WIDTH)
y = min(max(y, 0), HEIGHT)
```

Furthermore, note that your player sprite has a width and height of its own. The `x,y` coordinate represents the location of the top-left corner of the sprite. If you want to restrict the sprite's position such that the entire thing is always on the screen, you first need to get the size of the sprite

```
spriteWidth, spriteHeight = player.get_rect().size
```

And then factor that size into your boundary calculation

```
x = min(max(x, 0), WIDTH - spriteWidth)
y = min(max(y, 0), HEIGHT - spriteHeight)
```

Additionally, you need to make sure you do this *before* you call `screen.blit(player, (x, y))`, or else the sprite will be drawn with the original, unbounded coordinates.

Comment: I was watching some stuff on youtube and forgot to delete the code that was in the video.

Comment: I'm trying to make a boundary so that the player doesn't move past the boundary.

Comment: I tried what you said to do but I wasn't working.Other than that nothing.

Comment: You need to give more details. What isn't working? How is it not working? Are you getting an error? What would you like it to be doing that it's not? What would you like it not to be doing that it is?

Comment: My problem is my player has a border somehow to the left and top side of the screen but not of the bottom and right side here a video of the program.   https://vid.me/4amG

Comment: @James_Ikeler I've update my answer with more information.

Comment: Thanks it worked but I had to add a little bit of more code in order to get it to work.